# Finding and outputting characters in certain positions of a string

Tags: matlab

I am looking to output the characters of a string in certain positions using MATLAB, for example:

I want to find the characters in the positions 1, 3 and 5 in the string `'ABCDEF'` and output them, with the desired output being `ACE`.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include any attempts you made at solving this problem in a [mcve], as this is not a website where people just ask for code. Personal effort is appreciated. As to the question, check the `ismember` function, or the third output of `unique`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply index the character array

```
a='abcdef';
```

use an array of indices to index

```
a([1,3,5])

ans = 
ace
```